# Javascript, dependencies between objects

Tags: javascript, dom-events

On my form I have checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, textbox1 and textbox2.

By default only checkbox1 is active. When I click(check) checkbox1, checkbox2 is activated. When I click(check) checkbox2, checkbox3 is activated. Finally when I check checkbox3, textbox1 and textbox2 are activated.

And when I uncheck checkbox3, both textboxes are disabled. Checkbox2 with uncheck state disables checkbox3.

How can I maintain dependencies between these objects? For example, when I uncheck checkbox1, checkboxes 2 and 3 and both textboxes should disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the DOM elements for your checkboxes and inputboxes then I would say just add a user defined attribute in checkbox and inputbox elements. Some thing like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"  dependents="inputbox1,inputbox2" />
```

and onclick you can in your eventhandler access this attribute like

```
arrDependents = element.getAttribute("dependents").split(",");
```

this will return you all the dependent ID's as array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.  In this case, I have it unchecking checkboxes when they are disabled.  If that's not desired, change as needed:

**HTML:**

```
Checkbox 1: <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" onchange="onCheckbox1Changed();"/>
Checkbox 2: <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" onchange="onCheckbox2Changed();"/>
Checkbox 3: <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" onchange="onCheckbox3Changed();"/>
Textbox 1: <textarea id="textbox1"></textarea>
Textbox 2: <textarea id="textbox2"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Initialize checkboxes
    onCheckbox1Changed();
    onCheckbox2Changed();
    onCheckbox3Changed();
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var onCheckbox1Changed = function(checkbox){
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2');

    if(checkbox1.checked){
        checkbox2.disabled = false;
    } else {
        if(checkbox2.checked){
            checkbox2.click();
        }
        checkbox2.disabled = true;
    }
};

var onCheckbox2Changed = function(checkbox){
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2');
    var checkbox3 = document.getElementById('checkbox3');

    if(checkbox2.checked){
        checkbox3.disabled = false;
    } else {
        if(checkbox3.checked){
            checkbox3.click();
        }
        checkbox3.disabled = true;
    }
};

var onCheckbox3Changed = function(checkbox){
    var checkbox3 = document.getElementById('checkbox3');
    var textbox1 = document.getElementById('textbox1');
    var textbox2 = document.getElementById('textbox2');

    var disabled = !(checkbox3.checked);
    textbox1.disabled = disabled;
    textbox2.disabled = disabled;
};
```